I have only one get request. but i want to run the same request parallely with multiple users. how can i do that using jmeter
one get request needs be hit with multiple users. lets say, 50 users should hit the same GET API parallely. how can i do that on jmeter. please help.
tried with jp@gc parallel controller but not able to figureout the actual solution.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

If you need to hit the endpoint with 50 concurrent users add 50 threads to the Thread Group and specify the desired number of iterations and/or test duration. Below configuration will run 50 users for 30 seconds:


In case if you additionally want to execute 50 requests at exactly the same moment you can add Synchronizing Timer and set the "Number of simulated users to group by" to 50

See A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers article for more information on this and other JMeter Timers


